# I think I broke Kubuntu; boot from USB, mount FS, then install what I uninstalled?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, data-recovery

I am booting #! Linux from a USB drive in the hopes that I can either

1. Install what I uninstalled to get Kubuntu working again... (see https://superuser.com/questions/363695/installed-kde-in-ubuntu-removed-lightgdm-cannot-boot) OR
2. Copy over all of the files in my home directory to #!, then `rsync`/`scp` to another computer.

The first option is preferable, considering the amount of time I spent trying to customize Ubuntu.

Here is what happened: I was unsatisfied with `lightdm` so I uninstalled it (`purge`?) in the hopes that I could use KDE with `gdm`... So that failed. Is there a way that I could fix what I messed up and get KDE to play nice with `gdm`? Or just remove KDE completely? That's probably the best idea.

Comment: Tell me, why do you want to use Gnome Desktop Manager with KDE? Why not use kdm? I'd say it could work, but...

Comment: @jpaugh I'm open to just removing KDE. It was a bad decision anyway...

Comment: You mentioned in the other post that apt-geting does'nt work. Do you  mean `apt-get install gdm` fails? What kind of error message?

Comment: Incidentally, if you copy your home directory (including the .* hidden files/folders), it should keep most of your customizations--any that didn't require admin privileges to set.

Comment: @jpaugh it gives me a strange `not locking directory` error, and also `gdm` is installed already. where do i find the local filesystem?